# com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.FileUpload how to set text?

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, gxt

I want to use this class com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.FileUpload for file uploading but I faced with the  next issue. I cannot find how to set text programmatically. I mean in TextBox I have setText method to do it. How can I do it in FileUpload?

Comment: Set text means inside the textbox or name of the textbox ?inside that textbox you want to set some text ??

Comment: I want to set text inside of the textbox of FileUpload. I mean some path to the file wich is needed to be upload

Answer (score 2):

You cannot set,Since GWT file upload wraps with html `input type="file"`.So there is no way to set set `filename  or path (text)`  to that.

That should be select by user only,for sure.

You can only get from it.

If you are talking about  setting some name to your control  like `"select file"`,take a `lable` and add.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Security

> JavaScript and the DOM provide the potential for malicious authors to deliver scripts to run on a client computer via the web. Browser authors contain this risk using two restrictions. First, scripts run in a sandbox in which they can only perform web-related actions, not general-purpose programming tasks like creating files. Second, scripts are constrained by the same origin policy: scripts from one web site do not have access to information such as usernames, passwords, or cookies sent to another site

Comment: No, I was talking about the text (path to the file)

Comment: @AntonKasyanchuk Unfortunately you cannot due to security reasons.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As i understand I cannot change value attribute for input type="file" or maybe there is some trick in javascript to do that (I mean using DOM)?

Comment: @AntonKasyanchuk There is some security policy,So you can't.

Comment: Thank you so much. Can you have a look on my other topic about gwt? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18762882/how-to-set-multipart-encoding-in-the-formpanel-gwt-ext)

Comment: @AntonKasyanchuk  I did'nt use get-ext before but setting true for this method is enough I guess.http://gwt-ext.com/docs/2.0.4/com/gwtext/client/widgets/form/FormPanel.html#setFileUpload(boolean)